# Replace a value in a Pandas Dataframe with condition with one line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to do this operation in one line ?

```
df.loc[(df['A'] < 0), 'A'] = 0
df.loc[(df['B'] < 0), 'B'] = 0
```

Maybe it exists a Pandas function or maybe I can add arguments in this function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.clip_lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip_lower.html) with subset of columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[-1,20,24], 'B':[-1,2,-3], 'C':[-1,-2,-3]})
print (df)
    A  B  C
0  -1 -1 -1
1  20  2 -2
2  24 -3 -3

df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].clip_lower(0)
print (df)
    A  B  C
0   0  0 -1
1  20  2 -2
2  24  0 -3
```